# Delete a question on this site

Tags: discussion

How can you delete a question on this site?

Comment: In what context?

Comment: The reason why you wish to have it deleted will dictate the process.

Comment: For regular users, with enough rep, you can vote to delete and it takes 3 votes to do it. Or if it is your own question (with no upvoted answers) or answer you can just do it outright.